# Have a main Activity that calls another Activity

Tags: android

My Activity calls another Activity during which , the app should move to other activity and should not affect the main Activity.Should the main activity be onPause()  ?
and after the second Activity comes back to the Main Activity  should it have OnResume()?

if you have any example will be great.

thanks for helping!!!

Answer (score 0):

No rather you should use `startActivityforResult(intent, requestCode)` to start the next activity

and then override

```
protected void onActivityResult( final int requestCode,
                         final int resultCode, 
                      final Intent data)
```

See [Returning a Result from a Screen](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html)

That way you will know *which* activity was called before returning to main

Comment: yes i have done that already but i  thought that i need not take care of the of situation (onPause,OnResume....)

Comment: It depends on your source code. I think when you add more screens it can get confusing. Also for example if your main activity has a keypad  open onResume wont be called.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Intents, there is no need for pause and resume, provided the flow of your activity is fine. Suppose you are going from A to B, all you do is mention the current activity name and the next activity where it should go. 
For Ex:
Intent i = new Intent(ClassA.this,ClassB.class); where you are in class A and you are going to classB

Comment: i have done that and its working but when i am using the second activity, and i am going to my first activity i have an error : ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27007): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-15 18:29:04.967: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27007): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.TravelTop/com.TravelTop.Ego}: java.lang.NullPointerException
so i thought it is related